# CSS centering an element and floating another element to the right of it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a centered element on a page, and have another element to the right of it that displays some info. I've tried floating the element to the right, and it looks good for me, but I have a big display. I resized the browser window and it pushes the centered element down, which I don't want. I want it to be like on this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAJWw.jpg, where the photo container element is centered, and the thing to the right with all the links is to the right of it, but when you make the display smaller nothing gets pushed down, but the right element just gets moved out of the browser window. 
My css looks like this, #image is the div I want to have centered, and #info and .sharebutton are what I want to the right of it:

```
#image {
    max-width: 900px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}
#info, .sharebutton {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

I tried setting a clear:both on the image element, but for some reason this warps my #info and .sharebutton elements to the left side of the page. Thanks.

EDIT: My HTML:

```
<div id="info">
    <ul>
        <li>Uploaded: {{time}}</li>
        <br>
        <li>Views: {{view_count}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sharebutton">
        <a href="#openModal">
            <button id="share">Click Me</button>
        </a>

        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>Modal Box</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<article>
    <div id="image">
        <a href="{{source}}">
            <img src="{{source}}" />
        </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach is something like this:

```
article {margin: 0 200px;}
#info {width: 190px;}
```

That keeps the centered area out of the way of the sidebar items.

Comment: Works well, though in the end I decided having it under the first element rather than beside it looked better. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For `#info, .sharebutton` use `margin-right:0` insted float

Answer (score 0):

let's do this a little differently :)

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/4xx7Y/)

Here there are two big blocks: `div#image` and `div#info`. Both are floated to the left. The `<body>` is centered with `margin: 0 auto` and a `max-width`.

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
/* Center body */
max-width: 900px;
}
#image {
max-width: 900px;
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
#info, .sharebutton {
float: left;
}
```

HTML - slightly different... `<article>` first.

```
<article>
    <div id="image"> <a href="{{source}}">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x400">
        </a>

    </div>
</article>
<div id="info">
    <ul>
        <li>Uploaded: {{time}}</li>
        <li>Views: {{view_count}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sharebutton">
        <button id="share">Click Me</button>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

             <h2>Modal Box</h2>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```